# Jquery - click on element generated by jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have a jquery slider ([nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)) that generates the next and prev button with jquery. I'm trying to add a hide() action for a div on that buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nivo-prevNav").live('click', function() {
      $("#slide3").hide();
   });
});
```

`.nivo-prevNav` class is generated by the jquery function of slider

Any ideas on how I can fix this because it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` has been deprecated. Use `.on()` instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".nivo-prevNav", function() {
     $("#slide3").hide();
});
```

---

For better performance, you should call `.on()` on the closest parent that's available before the Nivo plugin runs:

```
$("#nivo-wrapper").on("click", ".nivo-prevNav", function() {
     $("#slide3").hide();
});
```

You should change `#nivo-wrapper` to whatever element you're calling the Nivo Slider on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on("click", ".nivo-prevNav", function() {
              $("#slide3").hide();
              });
        });
```

Change "live" to "on". Live is depreciated in the newest version of jQuery.

Comment: Actually, it's been deprecated for quite a while. It was _removed_ in 1.9.